# Psychopy not getting all the answers

Tags: psychopy

I'm using psychopy to build a cognitive task.
I have 5 circles on the screen and the participant needs to pressed on the good circle.
My code :

```
if mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_1):
    continueRoutine = False
    # save data if you like:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 1)
    thisExp.addData('RT', t)

elif mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_2):
    # save data if you like:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 0)
    thisExp.addData('RT', t)
    continueRoutine = True
elif mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_3):
    # save data if you like:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 0)
    thisExp.addData('RT', t)
    continueRoutine = True
elif mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_4):
    # save data if you like:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 0)
    thisExp.addData('RT', t)
    continueRoutine = True

elif mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_5):
    # save data if you like:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 0)
    thisExp.addData('RT', t)
    continueRoutine = True
```

The problem is that my datafile only contains the response time (RT) and the info of the circle_1. I would have no idea if the participant tried other circle before pressing on circle_1.

Question : How can I have in my csv file infos about all the times a participant pressed the mouse bouton.Maybe before pressing cercle_1, he pressed the cercle_3. Right now, I only have how long it took to get the correct answer.

Comment: I see the problem, but what is the specific question you are asking?

Comment: How to see the information of all the time a participant pressed the mouse bouton

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Comment: BTW, this could be easily rewritten as a *much* shorter and easier to read loop, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to record a sequence of events in the trial. This can be hard to find an appropriate data structure for, but in your case, I can think of two solutions.

## Record the number of wrong responses

Have a column (e.g. `n_wrong`) and count the number of non-circle_1 responses. In **Begin routine** add

```py
n_wrong = 0
```

Then in **each frame** add:

```py
if mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_1):
    thisExp.addData('correct', 1)
    thisExp.addData('RT', t)
    continueRoutine = False

elif mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_2) or mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_3) or mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_4) or mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_5):
    thisExp.addData('correct', 0)
    thisExp.addData('RT', t)
    n_wrong += 1  # One more error recorded!

    # Now wait until the mouse release to prevent recording 60 wrong clicks per second!
    while any(mouse.getPressed()):
        pass
```

Then under **end routine** add:

```py
thisExp.addData('n_wrong', n_wrong)
```

## Record which circles were pressed

The other is to have a column for each circle and shift those from "unpressed" to "pressed" when they are clicked. Then the column `cercle1` would correspond to what you currently call the `correct` column. So under **begin routine**:

```py
# Mark all non-target cirlces as unpressed
thisExp.addData('cercle1', 0)
thisExp.addData('cercle2', 0)
thisExp.addData('cercle3', 0)
thisExp.addData('cercle4', 0)
thisExp.addData('cercle5', 0)
```

Then under **each frame** I would do this:

```py
if mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_1):
    thisExp.addData('cercle1', 1)
    continueRoutine = False
if mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_2):
    thisExp.addData('cercle2', 1)
if mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_3):
    thisExp.addData('cercle3', 1)
if mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_4):
    thisExp.addData('cercle4', 1)
if mouse.isPressedIn(cercle_5):
    thisExp.addData('cercle5', 1)
```

The latter approach could be extended with reaction times by adding columns called `cercle1_rt` etc. but then you'd also need to do the `while any(mouse.getPressed()): pass` trick to record the onset and not just the release.

Comment: thanks! but my column  'n_wrong' is empty even if I know I did an error ? It says that I pressed cercle2 but still says that I have no errors..

Comment: Weird, it works correctly here. Are you sure that you pasted the code into the correct tabs? And that you used the actual stimulus names of the routine?

Comment: it's weird, cause if I write n_wrong = 5 in the begin routine, at the end, in my csv I still get an empty column

Comment: Do you have many lines or just one line ? I only have one line appearing in my csv. If I pressed cercle_2 and then cercle_1, I will get a 1 in cercle1 and 1 in cercle2. But still my n_wrong has an empty cell.

Comment: I get one line for each trial. If I set n_wrong=5 and then press cercle_2 7 times, the trial reads 12 in n_wrong (5+7). If setting n_wrong to a value doesn't transfer that to your data, you must have either re-defined n_wrong to be zero or forgot to do addData on n_wrong. Your reply indicates that you used both solutions together. I guess that's possible, but try and just do one to keep it simple for debugging.